# Why the product of four electron operators is an interaction?

Tags: many-body, second-quantization

The product of an electron creation and an electron destruction operator, denoted by $c^\dagger_{i\sigma}c_{i\sigma}$ is not considered to be an interaction. But the product of four-electron operators, for example, $c^\dagger_{i\uparrow}c_{i\uparrow}c^\dagger_{i\downarrow}c_{i\downarrow}$, is an interaction. Why is this so? I understand that this is very basic to many-body physics. But I am no expert. If someone explains it simply, I'll appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: What are your doubts exactly? Are you familiar with the procedure of writing e.g. two-body interactions in terms of creation- and annihilation operators? For example, a one-body operator in 'first quantization' depends only on one particle coordinate, e.g. an external potential; these operators can be written in terms of (roughly) $a^\dagger_i a_j$, while two-body operators, like the Coulomb interaction, can be re-written as a product of four such operators.

Comment: In an interaction term, should there not be the coordinates of both the particles $\vec r$ and $\vec r'$?

Comment: In the Hubbard model, the interaction term is of the type $c^\dagger_{i\uparrow}c_{i\uparrow}c^\dagger_{i\downarrow}c_{i\downarrow}$. I do not see two coordinates here.

Comment: Again: Are you familiar with going from 'first quantization' to 'second quantization'? If not, I'd suggest to read the relevant section(s) in some standard text books. I don't understand the question, actually. Are you worried that e.g. for one-body operators, two indices appear and for two-body interactions, four indices appear?

Comment: @Jakob What is the best yet quick reference to these topics?

Comment: Any book on condensed matter physics or many-body physics, for example Atland Simons or  the lecture notes by J. Solovej 'Many Body Quantum Mechanics'. In general, there are a lot of lecture notes about 'second quantization' available, but I cannot name any particularly good one. As I said, any book on CM or many-body physics, but of course also the standard books on QFT.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a Hamiltonian of an oscillator: $\mathit{H}=\frac{p^2+x^2}{2}$. Kinetic and potential energies are quadratic in p and x but this is not an interaction. Switching to creation/anihilation variables: $\mathit{c}=\mathit{p}+ix, c^\dagger=p-ix$ does not change the order - the hamiltonian will still be quadratic. You may then consider two coupled oscillators: $H=\frac{p_1^2+x_1^2}{2}+\frac{p_2^2+x_2^2}{2}+(x_1-x_2)^2$. But we can "eliminate" this apparent interaction by transforming to noninteracting normal mode variables, because a quadratic form can be diagonalized. So in order to model a simplest nonremovable interaction you have to consider a form of the next higher even order 4.